# Path error when trying to access Log analytics workspace

Tags: python, azure, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-api-apps

I am trying to get the logs from the log analytics workspace in Azure. While trying to access the workspace using Python I was getting the PathNotFoundError as below.

```
monitor_resource_id = "/subscriptions/ec1e-4764-9ebf/resourceGroups/test_resource/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/test_workspace"

time_range = timedelta(days=7)

def authenticate():
    return DefaultAzureCredential()

def query_logs():
    credential = authenticate()
    try:
        logs_query_client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
        end_time = datetime.utcnow()
        start_time = end_time - time_range
        query = f"{log_query} | where TimeGenerated >= datetime({start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}) and TimeGenerated <= datetime({end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')})"
        timespan = (start_time, end_time)
        response = logs_query_client.query_workspace(monitor_resource_id, query, timespan=timespan)
        for table in response.tables:
            for row in table.rows:
                print(row)
    
    except HttpResponseError as e:
        print(f"HTTP Response Error: {e.message}")
        print(f"Response status code: {e.status_code}")
        print(f"Error details: {e.error}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

```
HTTP Response Error: (PathNotFoundError) The requested path does not exist
Code: PathNotFoundError
Message: The requested path does not exist
Response status code: 404
Error details: (PathNotFoundError) The requested path does not exist
Code: PathNotFoundError
Message: The requested path does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my **`code`** below to get the logs from Log Analytics (Modified a code a little code) and followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitor-query-readme?view=azure-python#logs-query):

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

rithwik_workspace_id = "3c62e221"
rithwik_log_query = "AzureMetrics"
time_range = timedelta(days=7)

def authenticate():
    return DefaultAzureCredential()

def rith_func():
    creds = authenticate()
    
    rithwik_client = LogsQueryClient(creds)
    end_time = datetime.utcnow()
    start_time = end_time - time_range
    rithwik_query = f"{rithwik_log_query} | where TimeGenerated >= datetime({start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')}) and TimeGenerated <= datetime({end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')})"
    tim = (start_time, end_time)
    response = rithwik_client.query_workspace( rithwik_workspace_id, rithwik_query, timespan=tim)
    for table in response.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            print(row)

rith_func()
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Here workspace id is not resource id . To get workspace id open your Log analytics workspace and then copy the id as below and use it:

[image]